# how to get image from the following scipt through jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I try this link

[jSoup to check if a span class exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993115/jsoup-to-check-if-a-span-class-exists)

but i want to get image url from the following script through jsoup.

```
    <ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-button-list a-vertical a-spacing-top-micro">
<li class="a-spacing-small item"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="thumb-action" data-thumb-action="{&quot;variant&quot;:&quot;MAIN&quot;,&quot;index&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}">
        <span class="a-button a-button-selected a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle a-button-focus"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit"><span class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
            <img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31XcCgGBePL._SS40_.jpg">
        </span></span></span>
    </span>
</span></li>
```

Comment: what selector did you try

Comment: i want to get img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
Elements anchors = doc.select("li span img");
```